# cleaning CSV in r

Tags: r, csv, dataset, data-cleaning

The aim is to clean up the data, the CSV is currently listed like

```
 CITY         TMR    SMIN    SMEAN    SMAX    PMIN    PMEAN    PMAX       PM2    PERWH    NONPOOR    GE65      LPOP
PROVIDEN    1096      30     163      349     56      119      223     116.1     97.9      83.9      109    58.5645
JACKSON      789      29      70      161     27       74      124      21.3     60.0      69.1       64    52.7195
JOHNSTOW    1072      88     123      245     70      166      452      15.8     98.7      73.3      103    54.4829
```

There are a total of 81 OBS but only 1 variable.

Although it looks correct, it is not properly spaced. All the info is in 1 col but needs to be spaced out to 13 col.

Is there a way in r to clean up this dataset or do I need to manually rewrite a new set of data?

```
structure(list(TABLE.V7..AIR.POLLUTION.DATA...PART1 = c(" CITY         TMR    SMIN    SMEAN    SMAX    PMIN    PMEAN    PMAX       PM2    PERWH    NONPOOR    GE65      LPOP", 
" PROVIDEN    1096      30     163      349     56      119      223     116.1     97.9      83.9      109    58.5645", 
" JACKSON      789      29      70      161     27       74      124      21.3     60.0      69.1       64    52.7195", 
" JOHNSTOW    1072      88     123      245     70      166      452      15.8     98.7      73.3      103    54.4829", 
" JERSEY C    1199     155     229      340     63      147      253    1357.2     93.1      87.3      103    57.8585", 
" HUNTINGT     967      60      70      137     56      122      219      18.1     97.0      73.2       93    54.0617"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please paste a reproducible sample of your data in the questions using the output of `dput(head(your_data))`

Comment: How did you read the file into R? Did you specify/check the separator value that can be specified usually?

Comment: is that what you were looking for Peter?

Comment: deschen, I only inputted "read.csv ("C:\\...\\...\\...\\airpollution.csv")

Comment: Yes but I think your first step should be as @deschen pointed out is to check how you are reading in the csv data, you should be able to set the arguments to whatever means of reading the csv to avoid having to post process the data to get it into columns. Check out `?read.csv` in particular the `sep` and `col.names` arguments.

Comment: So try `sep = ' '` in your read.csv code. generally check the help function with `?read.csv`.

Comment: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names